# How to detect if MySQL query is from cache?

Tags: php, mysql

Is there any method to find out if an executed query is retrieved from MySQL query cache?

Of course... there are a lot of methods to count the number of cached queries on general level (`SHOW STATUS LIKE '%qcache%'` etc), but I want to know specifically if the current executed query is loaded from MySQL cache.

For example, in PHP the function `mysql_insert_id();` returns the last inserted ID in a separate query.

In that direction, it would be a beauty to call a metadata function like `mysql_is_query_from_cache($previous_query);` to verify that the previous query results are actually retrieved from MySQL query cache

Any ideas on this?

Comment: Why do you need that info? If you do not need data from cache build sql statement like "SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE id, name FROM customer"

Comment: Yes @glavić, indeed I can use `SQL_NO_CACHE` to avoid that the query is being cached.

But I wanna know **if the query is cached**, so I can finetune my query  and make sure that the results are always coming from cache. 

Right now there is no indicator which tells me if the results are coming from query cache or coming directly from the database engine. Please help me find this indicator :)

Comment: "results are always coming from cache" - check stats, and if needed increase the cache size. but note that's not necessary a good thing to do.

Comment: Thanks @KarolyHorvath, but I'm not looking for the general stats, but specifically if the current executed query is loaded from cache or not

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For MySQL 5.0 and higher you can use SHOW PROFILES to get a list of recent query IDs and then SHOW PROFILE FOR QUERY %id_here% to see if there was a reference to cached data.

This is explained in more details at http://www.dbasquare.com/2012/04/03/was-a-query-served-from-mysql-query-cache/ along with some other ways around.

Comment: Thanks @yuriy, I've made a codesample in PHP (see answer) and it works like a charm. I'm very happy with these directions! :)

Answer (score 6):

Thank you @yuriy, I've made a codesample with your 'SHOW PFOFILE' suggestion and it works like a charm!
The 'SHOW PROFILE FOR QUERY 2' command gives a very pretty result with "sending cached result to client", that was exactly the trigger I was looking for! :)

`/* enable profiling */`
`$result = mysql_query('SET profiling = 1');`

`/* is profiling ON for this session? */`
`$result = mysql_query("SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%profiling%'");`

`/* execute main query */`
`$result = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders');`

`/* show overview of current profiles */`
`$result = mysql_query('SHOW PROFILES');`

`/* show profiling stats for main query */`
`$result = mysql_query('SHOW PROFILE FOR QUERY 2');`

http://dbm.home.xs4all.nl/mysqlshowprofile2.jpg

Answer (score 2):

you can execute the same query twice and check their profile, for example

```
set global query_cache_size = 16777216;
set profiling = 1;
```

execute your query twices

```
select * from sbtest.sbtest1 limit 100;
select * from sbtest.sbtest1 limit 100;
```

and then check profile and you will see the second query cost less time than the first query

```
mysql> show profiles;
+----------+------------+----------------------------------------+
| Query_ID | Duration   | Query                                  |
+----------+------------+----------------------------------------+
|        7 | 0.20415325 | set global query_cache_size = 16777216 |
|        8 | 0.26780725 | select * from sbtest.sbtest2 limit 100 |
|        9 | 0.00007350 | select * from sbtest.sbtest2 limit 100 |
+----------+------------+----------------------------------------+
```

compare with query_ID=8 (ther first query) and query_ID=9 (the second query) using "show profile for query ID"

```
mysql> show profile for query 8;
+--------------------------------+----------+
| Status                         | Duration |
+--------------------------------+----------+
| starting                       | 0.000023 |
| Waiting for query cache lock   | 0.000004 |
| checking query cache for query | 0.032402 |
| checking permissions           | 0.000088 |
| Opening tables                 | 0.000035 |
| System lock                    | 0.000014 |
| Waiting for query cache lock   | 0.049689 |
| init                           | 0.075707 |
| optimizing                     | 0.000015 |
| statistics                     | 0.000021 |
| preparing                      | 0.000012 |
| executing                      | 0.000004 |
| Sending data                   | 0.108332 |
| Waiting for query cache lock   | 0.000013 |
| Sending data                   | 0.000581 |
| end                            | 0.000012 |
| query end                      | 0.000062 |
| closing tables                 | 0.000020 |
| freeing items                  | 0.000013 |
| Waiting for query cache lock   | 0.000003 |
| freeing items                  | 0.000741 |
| Waiting for query cache lock   | 0.000006 |
| freeing items                  | 0.000002 |
| storing result in query cache  | 0.000005 |
| logging slow query             | 0.000003 |
| cleaning up                    | 0.000004 |
+--------------------------------+----------+
26 rows in set (0.49 sec)
```

you can see a long list such as open tables, close tables and so on, it means that this query needs to query data from hard disk, and the second one is

```
mysql> show profile for query 9;
+--------------------------------+----------+
| Status                         | Duration |
+--------------------------------+----------+
| starting                       | 0.000023 |
| Waiting for query cache lock   | 0.000004 |
| checking query cache for query | 0.000008 |
| checking privileges on cached  | 0.000003 |
| checking permissions           | 0.000010 |
| sending cached result to clien | 0.000019 |
| logging slow query             | 0.000003 |
| cleaning up                    | 0.000003 |
+--------------------------------+----------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

it proves that the query is cached

Answer (score -1):

Be careful with this.

```
SELECT * FROM orders;
```

is not from cache (query id = qId1)

```
SELECT * FROM orders;
```

is from cache (query id changes!, query id=qId2)

```
DELETE FROM orders;
```

query with id=qId2 is from cache, but really it is not! (table data changes). You need to execute query one more time. But it is necessary to know if query is from cache BEFORE executing. And that's why Yuriy's method doesn't work.

Comment: I feel there is some potentially important information in your answer, but I just can't figure out what your trying to convey.